# QGIS doesn't display compound polygon (from a spatial oracle DB)

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, oracle-spatial

When I want to display the elements stored in a spatial oracle DB, the compound elements aren't display. There is no error message.

The type of these compound elements is "1005".

Are these elements managed by QGIS? Can you suggest me how to display this type of polygon?

I'm using Oracle database 11g (11.2.0.1.0) and QGIS 2.16.0

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96630/sdo_objrelschema.htm)'s suggests these are constructed using straight lines and arcs

> SDO_ETYPE values 4, 1005, and 2005 considered compound elements. They
>   contain at least one header triplet with a series of triplet values
>   that belong to the compound element. For SDO_ETYPE values 1005 and
>   2005, the first digit indicates exterior (1) or interior (2):
>
> 1005: exterior polygon ring (must be specified in counterclockwise
>   order)
>
> 2005: interior polygon ring (must be specified in clockwise order)
>
> Compound polygon with some vertices connected by straight line
>   segments and some by circular arcs. The value, n, in the
>   Interpretation column specifies the number of contiguous subelements
>   that make up the polygon. The next n triplets in the SDO_ELEM_INFO
>   array describe each of these subelements. The subelements can only be
>   of SDO_ETYPE 2. The end point of a subelement is the start point of
>   the next subelement, and it must not be repeated. The start and end
>   points of the polygon must be the same.
>
> See Section 2.3.4 and Figure 2-5 for an example of a geometry using
>   this type.

From the [OGR documentation](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRCompoundCurve.html) it appears that support for these features is only available since version 2.0. If you go to the `help` menu and select `about` it will tell you which version of GDAL/OGR your version was compiled against. If it is less than 2.0 then you will need to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have checked the versions in the "about" menu of QGIS. GDAL/OGR version is 2.1.0.

Comment: can you try ogrinfo from the command line?

Comment: QGIS has a native oracle provider which is not looped through OGR.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn - I didn't know that, does it support compound features?

Comment: [Probably not](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/oracle/qgsoracleconn.cpp#L536-L597) I guess it wouldn't be hard to add it if there was somebody interested.

Comment: Just to be sur : You confirm that the compound objects aren't supported by the native oracle provider from qgis?! Does the add of the compound elements is done necessarily with a futur patch of qgis or does it exist a way to add them with the current version?